# What is the reason to save Firebase authVerificationID?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication

When logging a user in or signing the user up for the first time and using [phone auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) it says:

> Save the verification ID and restore it when your app loads. By doing
> so, you can ensure that you still have a valid verification ID if your
> app is terminated before the user completes the sign-in flow (for
> example, while switching to the SMS app).

I'm not exactly sure what is the purpose of saving it.

0- the user opens the app and they are on the Login screen

1- the user adds their phone number (below)

2- the callback receives the `authVerificationID`

3- before the user is taken to the SMS screen, the app is somehow terminated

4- when the user opens the app again, because they haven't logged in yet, they are right back on the Login screen. When they enter their phone number again, they receive either a brand new `authVerificationID` or the same one (I'm not sure), and they are taken to the SMS screen. Either way **both are valid** and will get them to the SMS screen.

**What does saving the `authVerificationID` do when no matter what, if the app is terminated, they have to add their phone number again because they will be back on the Login screen?**

If the answer is "c*heck if the authVerificationID is saved, and if it is then bring them to the SMS screen instead of the Login screen*" then that is bad ux. The user might come back an hour later, when they first open the app they will see the SMS screen and be confused.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in

    guard let verificationID = verificationID else { return }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID") // how does this help me?

    // A. take user to sms view controller
    // B. use authVerificationID && verificationCode for sms sign-in
}
```

Comment: The answer is pretty what you said - if the user leaves your app in the middle of the auth flow, you can bring them back to the SMS screen straight-away. Once the user leaves your app, you have no guarantees whether the app will not be terminated. It depends entirely on the OS, so your user might end up in a cycle where they just can't complete the sign-up (however unlikely). As for bad UX comment - it's very subjective, and very time-dependent.

Comment: @NewDev thanks for the help. If you add this as answer I will accept it. You are about my example being subjective. If they come right back, then yeah bring them to the sms screen. If they come back later then I think not. To make things easy I’d rather just bring them to the login screen if the app is terminated and they have logged in yet. Subjective 

Comment: You could, but they *could* get stuck in the endless cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty much what you said - if the user leaves your app in the middle of the auth flow, you can you can resume the sign-in flow from where they left off - i.e. the SMS verification step.

Once the user leaves your app, you have *no guarantees* that your app will not be terminated. It depends entirely on the OS. So your user might end up in a cycle where they just can't complete the sign-up (however unlikely this case is).

As for bad UX comment - it's very subjective (and depends on your design), and also time-dependent.